# Why UEFI bootable disks take the first boot priority in UEFI BIOS?

Tags: boot, bios, uefi, secure-boot

I see several times that in Mainboards with `UEFI BIOS` every bootable media with UEFI option automatically takes the first boot priority, I want to know what's the reason for this behavior and how to stop this?

Comment: You need to be able to to boot from USB (or CD) in the event your hard drive fails (happens).  Secure boot prevents booting from unauthorized sources. In your case, Acronis is authorized which is why it works. So having USB first in the boot order is correct and what you should do.

Comment: you're right but at this time i want to set password on my bios and block booting from other devices like cd and usb.

Comment: Starts function differently than restarts with respect to BIOS (to allow updates to continue to proceed) so I am not sure you can do what you suggest in all cases). Secure boot really does protect your computer.